# How to implement button SetOnClickListener in a fragment?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, fragment, onclicklistener

I'm working on a small project and I want to use a Slider Menu. Long story short I happen to find a source code of a slider menu using drawer from some website and it works very well on my device. However I'm a little bit confused migrating my previous activity into this slider menu because they use fragment for each individual item on the listView.

To simple things up I want to migrate an activity that capable of do a Ping function. it's xml file consist of one EditText, a Button, and a TextView for showing the output.

Now I did manage to "successfully" migrating that activity into this fragment. The drawer runs well, but I got stuck because the app always force close after I click on the ping button.

***PS: I haven't change the class name yet, pardon me***

Below are my code:

this is my original Ping activity:

```
package my.jlm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Ping extends Activity {
    EditText edit;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ping);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edit.setText("192.168.1.1");
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Editable host = edit.getText();
    try {
    String pingCmd = "ping -c 5 " + host;
    String pingResult = "";
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    text.setText(inputLine + "\n\n");
    pingResult += inputLine;
    text.setText(pingResult);
    }
    in.close();
    }//try
    catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }


    }
    });
    }}
```

this FindPeopleFragment.java (this should be the PingFragment.java).
I thought this was a successful attempt because eclipse didn't show any red mark, but if Im wrong please correct me.

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment 
        implements OnClickListener
{
        EditText edit;
        TextView text;
        Button button;





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ping, container, false);


        EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edit.setText("192.168.1.1");
        text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);





        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editable host = edit.getText();
        try {
        String pingCmd = "ping -c 5 " + host;
        String pingResult = "";
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        text.setText(inputLine + "\n\n");
        pingResult += inputLine;
        text.setText(pingResult);
        }
        in.close();
        }//try
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

};;
```

and finally this is my Manifest for above project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="my.jlm.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="museumjakarta.source.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my LogCat error log:

```
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 1267
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.FindPeopleFragment.onClick(FindPeopleFragment.java:53)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-15 09:07:41.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

to simplify here is what I experienced:
the Ping xml page shows up after I click from the Drawer ListView, however when I click the Ping Button inside it, the application crashed, resulting the above error log. Help me resolve this problem and thank you very much.

PS: I'm using eclipse adt because I can't run AS on my AMD processor.

edit: thought it may help, i will post the mainActivity.java for this fragment:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling FindPeopleFragment

Comment: I'm calling the fragment from MainActivity.java, it use array function to call each fragments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code lines:

```
button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(this); // Best Solution <---
button.setOnClickListener(rootView);
```

or

```
button.setOnClickListener(getActivity());
```

---

Then, you have to call the `onClick()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // CODE TO DO
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, you can do:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your Code Lines
    }
```

### EDIT

*I think your code is fine. The only thing you have to do is adding: **`button.setOnClickListener(this);`** then, add the **`switch`** statement for **`v.getId()`** in your **`OnClick`** method.*

### EDIT2

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment
implements View.OnClickListener {
        EditText edit;
        TextView text;
        Button button;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ping, container, false);


            EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            edit.setText("192.168.1.1");
            text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    Editable host = edit.getText();
                    try {
                        String pingCmd = "ping -c 5 " + host;
                        String pingResult = "";
                        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(inputLine);
                            text.setText(inputLine + "\n\n");
                            pingResult += inputLine;
                            text.setText(pingResult);
                        } in .close();
                    } //try
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    break;
                    case default:
                    log.i("Inf", "there's no click");
                    break;
            }
     }
     }
```

### EDIT3

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment
implements OnClickListener {
        EditText edit;
        TextView text;
        Button button;
        Editable Edit2 ;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ping, container, false);


            EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            edit.setText("192.168.1.1");
            Edit2 = edit.getText();
            text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);

            return rootView;
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:


                    try {
                        String pingCmd = "ping -c 5 " + Edit2;
                        String pingResult = "";
                        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(inputLine);
                            text.setText(inputLine + "\n\n");
                            pingResult += inputLine;
                            text.setText(pingResult);
                        } in .close();
                    } //try
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    break;


            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(this); // Best Solution <---

button.setOnClickListener(rootView);

when I add the last code it shows error, and the quickfix would be "cast argument rootview"

and also i added the switch statement too and it still doesn't work. the app crash when i click on the button.

Comment: @Arya Not rootView put (this) instead

Comment: so there would be two button.setOnClickListener(this); ? i tried too and still crashed.

Comment: @Arya put `button.setOnClickListener(getActivity());`

Comment: @Arya Replace your `FindPeopleFragment` for my Edit 2, let me know if it works

Comment: i changed the (this) into (getActivity()); and the quickfix suggest button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) getActivity()); . and the app crashed when i click on the listview.

Comment: ouch my mistake, i just read your edit 2 just now. i will try it now

Comment: Let me see if I get what you want to do... this Ping activity you want to use it as a Fragment?

Comment: well, yes, because this ping activity is my only ping function that works in activity, I dont have any source to do a ping function inside a fragment, so i just rely on this activity hoping to "migrating" it into a fragment. and by the way i tried your edit 2 and it shows error in "default"  Syntax error on token "default", invalid ConstantExpression FindPeopleFragment.java

Comment: Coul you send me a screenshot?

Comment: here is my screenshot for the error: http://i60.tinypic.com/2e2pf8o.jpg I can't do anything since eclipse won't show the quickfix for this error message

Comment: @Arya just delete the case default :P

Comment: I did follow your suggestion and the app crashed when i try to click the button, showing this 

03-19 08:05:52.622: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @Arya I would like to see your full code... That's how I could help you

Comment: I exported the slider menu (with Ping.java and activity_ping inside) project into a zip file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaTqUC3A_rQZ3VZZlREMGp4QW8/view?usp=sharing , i hope you don't mind, & thank you very much for this, i really appreciate it.

I want to add googleMaps function and phone call function in the future, maybe if you could explain to me about migrating the activity into the fragment in a simple language later, i could understand it more better. But for now, let it be the Ping activity first, because I want to focus on learning in this

Comment: @Arya, I think I solved it... I don't know what you want to do but at least it doesn't crash, just copy my edit 3...

Comment: @Arya If that was what you wanted to do, feel free to upvote my answer and accept it as a correct ;)

Comment: it is? wow.. i'll check that tomorrow evening on the real phone (i will use my friend's phone) and yeah i'll accept your answer as a correct just now. but if i get trouble tomorrow, please let me contact you again here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73364/discussion-between-skizo-and-arya).

Answer (score 2):

Just change your button listener assignment like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(FindPeopleFragment.this);
```

because you have to pass the reference of the class which has implemented `OnClickListener`. If you write `this` like this way     `button.setOnClickListener(this);` it will pass current activity context in place of current fragment reference.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I did try to write it but still doesn't work.

Comment: yes, same error in logcat and the app crash when i click the ping button

Comment: both in fragment and activity, yes. I use activity_ping.xml and the ping result should show up on the same page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Change your listener set line in `onCreateView`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

to be:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: thaks for your quick response and i'm sorry for the late reply.

i did use button.setOnClickListener(this); and with my old fragment code, and also with @Apurva code, still doesn't work. The ping button doesn't cause app crash, but it still won't run the activity given. any idea?